# AlterProcedureException when I try update-database command EF6 MYSQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to alter a table in Entity Framework 6 with mysql connectors.

The error is:

```
PM> update-database -verbose
Using StartUp project 'Facade'.
Using NuGet project 'DAL'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'GiveAndGet' (DataSource: localhost, Provider: MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201602122108206_2].
Applying explicit migration: 201602122108206_2.
System.NotImplementedException: AlterProcedureOperation
   en MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   en System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   en System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
AlterProcedureOperation
```

My context is:

```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class GiveAndGetContext : DbContext
    {

        public GiveAndGetContext()
        : base("GiveAndGetContext")
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer(
            //     new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<GiveAndGetContext, DAL.Migrations.Configuration>("GiveAndGetContext"));

        }


        //Para crear des de presentation
        //  // Constructor to use on a DbConnection that is already opened
        //  public GiveAndGetContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        //: base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
        //  {

        //  }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<City>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Controller>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Interest>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Language>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Literal>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Province>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Region>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<View>().MapToStoredProcedures();
            modelBuilder.Entity<prueba>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        }
}
}

Configuration file of migrations is:

 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DAL.Context.GiveAndGetContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());

        }
```

My package.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.8" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.9.8" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

And example file of add-migration is:

```
 using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class _2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.pruebas", "Name", c => c.Short(nullable: false));
            AlterStoredProcedure(
                "dbo.prueba_Insert",
                p => new
                    {
                        IdController = p.Short(),
                        Name = p.Short(),
                    },
                body:
                    @"SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI';INSERT INTO `pruebas`(
                      `IdController`, 
                      `Name`) VALUES (
                      @IdController, 
                      @Name);
                      SELECT
                      `Id`
                      FROM `pruebas`
                       WHERE  row_count() > 0 AND `Id`=last_insert_id();"
            );

            AlterStoredProcedure(
                "dbo.prueba_Update",
                p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Short(),
                        IdController = p.Short(),
                        Name = p.Short(),
                    },
                body:
                    @"UPDATE `pruebas` SET `IdController`=@IdController, `Name`=@Name WHERE `Id` = @Id;"
            );

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.pruebas", "Name", c => c.String(unicode: false));
            throw new NotSupportedException("Scaffolding create or alter procedure operations is not supported in down methods.");
        }
    }
```

I can create a database with commands, and add a new table, but I can't modify a column of a table (drop column or add column). The problem isn't drop, it's `AlterStoredProcedure` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is: "System.NotImplementedException: AlterProcedureOperation"

And that's i was [found](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,632243,632322#msg-632322):

> Check out the manual page for stored routines ...
>
> "ALTER PROCEDURE | FUNCTION can modify only the characteristic and
>   comment of a stored procedure or function. However, you cannot change
>   the parameters or body of a stored procedure using this statement; to
>   make such changes, you must drop and re-create the procedure using
>   DROP PROCEDURE and CREATE PROCEDURE."

So try to change your migration to **DROP and CREATE instead of ALTER**